Can Laravel Reverb get user online/offline status in backend?
I'm building a web game based on Websocket, I need to know which user is online or offline in realtime.
I googled a little, and I found out it has to be the client-side to told server-side if user is online or offline. such as:
Echo.join('').here(e => {
    //ajax request to told server this user is online
}).leaving(e => {
    //ajax request to told server this user is offline
})

Howerver there is one problem:
If user disconnected accidently without trigger the leaving hook. Such as user's web browser crashed. Server-side may not know about user's offline status.
Maybe I can pull-in some heartbeat strategy, but I think there must be some better way to do this.
I notice that Echo is sending and retriving ping-pong messages. It's that mean Reverb is already detecting if user is offline？
If I can just get all online users list and listen to user's leaving event in server-side. then I can updating user status without involing client-side and reduce http requests.
So what is the best practice for doing this?

It's not documented but looking at the source, it does register some routes following Pusher's HTTP API. You can reference Pusher's documentation to see what what each of those routes can do.
Assuming you are using Presence Channels, you can get connected users by using /apps/{appId}/channels/{channel}/users. See Get users.
Reverb does clean up old connections where it hasn't received a pong back. See the PruneStaleConnections job. This is called within the Reverb server.
